# Run emacs using applescript and open file

Tags: applescript

What I would like to do is have an automator script open a file in emacs when I drag a file onto it, and bring terminal to the front.

Right now, when I try to do this with input set to ~/Desktop/test.txt, it either opens up the main page, or it ends up with ~/Desktop/testtxt. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

This is what I have right now:

```
set thePath to POSIX path of input
tell application "Terminal" to do script "emacs"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal"
        activate
        delay 2
        keystroke "x" using control down
        delay 1
        keystroke "f" using control down
        delay 1
        keystroke thePath
        delay 1
        keystroke return
        delay 1

    end tell
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the file path as an argument to `emacs`

```
on run {input}
    tell application "Terminal"
        repeat with i in input
            do script "emacs " & quoted form of POSIX path of i
        end repeat
        activate
    end tell
    return input
end run
```